Why does my interior door's paint job look so uneven?
I've done two coats of semigloss and the paint looks really uneven. I painted the grooves with a small brush and the flat surfaces with a foam roller. Does this mean I need to apply a third coat?
This is my first time painting a door. I've painted walls before and haven't had these issues.


Did you white-prime the door before painting it? Also, switching tools might change the amount of paint deposited.

Did you give it a day to dry.  The paint being different thicknesses can take different amounts of time to fully dry. That would make it look uneven in color if viewed before all the paint was dry.

@tripledefault the doors did come primed so I didn’t prime again. I’m going to try to use only brushes on the other side.

@RMDman I waited 2 hours between coats yesterday and this is how they look today.
